# Small item for a grandparent to send via mail

Tags: grandparents

My father-in-law enjoys sending small notes to my 5 year old son as a means of maintaining their connection. A few months ago he started sending one or two sheets of stickers as part of each envelope. The stickers were engaging, but interest has waned recently. Now my father-in-law is looking for ideas for other small items he can include in small to Letter-size envelopes. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

He could encode the letter (using a simple code) for your 5-year old to decode

Answer (score 1):

I love this idea, it's really sweet. Growing up I had a penpal and we would send each other cool buttons (we were both interested in fashion). I remember it being so much fun and a great way for us to hunt for them.

How about working on a small item collection for them to start and work on together? You can even have your son, send a letter with an item back too? A couple of ideas that are top of mind for me:

- Activity Card (Baseball, pokemon, collectible cards)
- small rocks or pebbles
- interesting coins
- leaf